# How do I get the position of a tkinter object?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, window

My issue is trying to get the position of an object on a tkinter window.
Below is my code:

```
def fireBullet(event):
        global playerMovementSpeed, player

        playerX = player.winfo_x()
        playerY = player.winfo_y()

        bullet.setx(playerX)
        bullet.sety(playerY)

        for i in range(40):
            c.move(bullet, 0, bulletMovementSpeed)

        return player
```

The issue is that I am having is with the playerX and playerY variables.

I have read through stackoverflow forums and geekforgeek pages. This method was quite commonly repeating and thought I'd have a go at it. The issue I am getting is the following:
`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'`

Comment: Please show the code that gives you that error, and please try to create a [mcve] we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Based on your code, `bullet` may be the item ID (an integer) of a *bullet* created in the canvas.  So `bullet.setx(...)` will raise exception.